# how to get twitter timeline in my android app?

Tags: android, twitter

I am using Twitter kit

https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android

I am able to login  using this [link](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Log-In-with-Twitter)

Now i need to show timeline of the user logged in

I tried to get user id

```
TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                long userId = session.getUserId();
```

and use it here

```
        UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().userId(userId).build();
```

but no thing appears

i tried this

```
SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder()
                    .query("#twitterflock")
                    .build();
```

and it works fine but what I need is showing the tweets which appears when i open my home in twitter, what method should i use and what parameters should i send?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        if (timeline != null) {

            try {
                timeline.previous(null, new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(final Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
                        // Do something here with your Tweet objects
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(final TwitterException ignored) {

                    }
                });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        }
```